# Scala Json.format on a case class that includes string or int

Tags: scala, play-json

I want to parse a Json file to a case class.

One of the fields (named X) in the json can be either a string or an int (in the db).

How can I use Json.format to parse that field?

If I use int or string I get an exception:

```
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((/X,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
```

This is my case class:
X is the field that can be a string or int.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json}

case class MyClass(Y: Option[String] = None, X: ???)
object MyClassDocument {
  implicit val MyClassDocumentFormat: Format[MyClassDocument] = Json.format [MyClassDocument]
}
```

I'm new to Scala, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The whole code is wrong. Is that the actual code ?

Comment: This is the relevant part. Of course ??? = Int or string (thats the type i'm looking for). But it works fine when the db contains only string or int type for X.

Comment: You can do some parsing (either string parsing or json parsing) and try to convert the result to int or string, BUT, don't do this, try to unify them, you can just store `x: String` in the db. you also can (not a good practice though) have both fields in the class as Optional and define your own `Reads` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You could type it as a `JsValue` and pattern match later:

```scala
case class MyClass(y: Option[String] = None, x: JsValue)

myClass match {
  case MyClass(_, JsNumber(_)) => ...
  case MyClass(_, JsString(_)) => ...
}
```

---

EDIT:

As stated in the comments, by doing so you are coupling the case class with a specific implementation of the JSON representation.

You should probably rather write a custom (de)serializer (`Reads` and/or `Writes`) than using the automatic `Json.format` macro.

Comment: Using a `JsValue` in the data model is usually the symptom of a bad design, as it couples the datamodel with one specific transport/representation format

Comment: This doesn't have to be the data model layer, it can be an intermediate case class representing the raw value which is then transformed to 2 differents data models. But yes agree you are adding coupling

Comment: But then it might make more sense to write a custom deserializer directly rather than relying on the `Json.format` macro

Comment: Intermediate case class/DTO are usually symptom of bad design, also, as it introduce redundancy and/or untyped data at some point

Comment: The use of JsValue solved the problem, however maybe it's better to use Reads instead. The problem is that this is a lot of code change (in this case).